# How to Get Passed Props Values in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass data to another page and use this data in that page in React.

I pass the data like below to home page:

```
this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/home',
      state: { a: a, b: b, c: c}
    })
```

In home page, I print the state on console like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.props.location.state);
}
```

It prints to the console, it works fine, however I want to print the state's a value. I tried to do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.props.location.state.a);
}
```

It gives an error saying "a is undefined". So how can I get the values in state?

Comment: can you add the console logged value here. Is console.log prints the whole object? if yes, You could also try destructuring. const {a, b, c} = this.props.location.state;

Comment: Console.log prints the whole Object. And I cannot access these Object values a, b and c. How can I use this const {a, b, c} = this.props.location.state ?

Comment: Please update your question to include (1) how the "/home" component is rendered, (2) your general routing setup (router, switch, links, etc...), and (3) the component you are navigating from. The error is saying that `a` is undefined with that component mounts, so either you are not receiving route props correctly or the component is already mounted and you are navigating later.